# R Plotly hooverinfo - put more info

Tags: r, plotly

please help, I am having this code:

```
HAMAG_pozivi_df %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~Ugovoreni_iznos_bespovratnih_potpora_HRK, 
    y = ~Broj_ugovora,                                                                                                size = ~Postotak_iskorištenosti,
    color = ~Poziv, 
    frame = ~Datum, 
    text = ~Poziv,
    hovertemplate = paste("<b>%{text} - ", %{Postotak_iskorištenosti}, "/b><br>"),
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers', marker = list(sizeref = 0.15))
```

Here is smaller example of the data:

dput(HAMAG_small)
structure(list(Poziv = c("Kompetentost i razvoj MSP", "Kompetentost i razvoj MSP",
"Kompetentost i razvoj MSP", "Kompetentost i razvoj MSP", "Kompetentost i razvoj MSP",
"Kompetentost i razvoj MSP", "Kompetentost i razvoj MSP", "Kompetentost i razvoj MSP",
"Kompetentost i razvoj MSP", "Kompetentost i razvoj MSP", "Kompetentost i razvoj MSP",
"Kompetentost i razvoj MSP", "Kompetentost i razvoj MSP", "Kompetentost i razvoj MSP",
"Kompetentost i razvoj MSP", "IKT", "IKT", "IKT", "IKT", "IKT",
"IKT", "IKT", "IKT", "IKT", "IKT", "IKT", "IKT", "IKT", "IKT",
"IKT", "E-impuls", "E-impuls", "E-impuls", "E-impuls", "E-impuls",
"E-impuls", "E-impuls", "E-impuls", "E-impuls", "E-impuls", "E-impuls",
"E-impuls", "E-impuls", "E-impuls", "E-impuls", "Certifikacija proizvoda",
"Certifikacija proizvoda", "Certifikacija proizvoda", "Certifikacija proizvoda",
"Certifikacija proizvoda", "Certifikacija proizvoda", "Certifikacija proizvoda",
"Certifikacija proizvoda", "Certifikacija proizvoda", "Certifikacija proizvoda",
"Certifikacija proizvoda", "Certifikacija proizvoda", "Certifikacija proizvoda",
"Certifikacija proizvoda", "Certifikacija proizvoda", "Internacionalizacija MSP I",
"Internacionalizacija MSP I", "Internacionalizacija MSP I", "Internacionalizacija MSP I",
"Internacionalizacija MSP I", "Internacionalizacija MSP I", "Internacionalizacija MSP I",
"Internacionalizacija MSP I", "Internacionalizacija MSP I", "Internacionalizacija MSP I",
"Internacionalizacija MSP I", "Internacionalizacija MSP I", "Internacionalizacija MSP I",
"Internacionalizacija MSP I", "Internacionalizacija MSP I"),
Sektor = c("Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo",
"Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo", "Poduzetništvo"
), Datum = c("2017-10", "2017-11", "2017-12", "2018-01",
"2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07",
"2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12", "2017-10",
"2017-11", "2017-12", "2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04",
"2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10",
"2018-11", "2018-12", "2017-10", "2017-11", "2017-12", "2018-01",
"2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07",
"2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12", "2017-10",
"2017-11", "2017-12", "2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04",
"2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10",
"2018-11", "2018-12", "2017-10", "2017-11", "2017-12", "2018-01",
"2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07",
"2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12"), Broj_ugovora = c(107,
113, 114, 184, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 187, 189, 191, 191,
191, 191, 228, 228, 228, 228, 228, 228, 228, 228, 228, 228,
228, 228, 228, 228, 228, 6, 271, 802, 1008, 1012, 1013, 1014,
1024, 1029, 1044, 1049, 1061, 1069, 1070, 1070, 1, 4, 8,
39, 45, 52, 62, 73, 81, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 0, 0, 0,
0, 28, 50, 58, 68, 73, 73, 73, 78, 80, 83, 87), Ugovoreni_iznos_bespovratnih_potpora_HRK = c(424033428.09,
467487690.95, 467487690.95, 804093521.54, 837499959.78, 837499959.78,
837499959.78, 837499959.78, 837499959.78, 837499959.78, 844649031.74,
855980062.68, 855980062.68, 855980062.68, 855980062.68, 102512676.83,
102512676.83, 102512676.83, 102512676.83, 102512676.83, 102512676.83,
102512676.83, 102512676.83, 102512676.83, 102512676.83, 102512676.83,
102512676.83, 102512676.83, 102512676.83, 102512676.83, 1524507.07,
63396814.17, 215523821.13, 232846932.65, 233667792.69, 233842042.69,
234095898.24, 236636983.44, 237847749.26, 241688594.5, 243060760.35,
245454496.35, 246917008.03, 247179729.43, 247179729.43, 470300,
855320.88, 4117308.32, 10205587.22, 11217184.85, 13345192.03,
15957743.79, 19517432.77, 21648500.97, 22998568.73, 22998568.73,
22998568.73, 22998568.73, 22998568.73, 22998568.73, 0, 0,
0, 0, 15829787.69, 27451241.51, 31654223.22, 35636657.62,
37698925.49, 37698925.49, 37698925.49, 39648358.64, 40994248.44,
41767238.27, 43041794.89), Ukupna_vrijednost_projekata_HRK = c(1197652047.39,
1317806139.58, 1333965773.53, 2337041986.44, 2426062662.15,
2426062662.15, 2426062662.15, 2426062662.15, 2426062662.15,
2426062662.15, 2431029122.77, 2466358118.04, 2466358118.04,
2466358118.04, 2466358118.04, 133702730.13, 133702730.13,
133702730.13, 133702730.13, 133702730.13, 133702730.13, 133702730.13,
133702730.13, 133702730.13, 133702730.13, 133702730.13, 133702730.13,
133702730.13, 133702730.13, 133702730.13, 2992433, 131902321.43,
385664018.76, 436149540.72, 437683429.1, 437883429.1, 437883429.1,
438883429.1, 438883429.1, 441687049.74, 443697771.92, 447454193.96,
449953071.71, 450918959.21, 450918959.21, 691625, 1227429.5,
5708826.16, 14907664.65, 16407627.16, 19810797.87, 23466354.25,
28494214.26, 31644291.89, 33227957.12, 33227957.12, 33227957.12,
33227957.12, 33227957.12, 33227957.12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22387814.41,
40599619.16, 46397267.22, 52133774.7, 55348229.51, 55348229.51,
55348229.51, 58433834.63, 61513519.63, 62892631.31, 72400645.09
), `Iznos_isplata (HRK)` = c(75789133.2, 83136010.22, 91837125.88,
123758549.01, 174078817.26, 218044373.88, 241207920.78, 277116801.81,
328873186.24, 342710770.12, 385117646.86, 414525145.93, 443852067.98,
475494170.61, 486138306.06, 57209507.48, 64179387.28, 67733447.32,
73802922.03, 78257488, 82859932.99, 83744309.32, 90780339.84,
92978310.5100001, 93491845.37, 93534735.1400001, 94924838.6300001,
95473446.6100001, 95488179.9000001, 95488179.9000001, 0,
0, 8326791.55, 56056248.24, 78451526.8, 90495747.4900001,
103555785.85, 128921861.73, 143996207.99, 165308191.32, 179240300.7,
189267648.02, 199167842.04, 204165531.53, 206617712.84, 0,
0, 0, 725267.73, 1881252.32, 2626494.13, 3086583.79, 4144696.31,
6573192.66, 7570534.16, 8289576.51, 8783616.53, 9388093.63,
9708338.45, 10561160.94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2493988.24, 4700301.13,
8223494.87, 9490542.6, 12063469.86, 14697439.6, 15757969.14,
16907111.65, 17327370.42, 17729744.63), Broj_završenih_ugovora = c(5,
6, 6, 10, 13, 17, 19, 26, 29, 36, 45, 60, 65, 71, 74, 54,
57, 70, 94, 108, 121, 140, 167, 189, 193, 200, 202, 204,
218, 218, 0, 0, 1, 4, 17, 47, 90, 176, 282, 389, 499, 571,
661, 706, 774, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 9, 15,
17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7), Iznos_bespovratne_potpore_završenih_ugovora_HRK = c(43015140,
43015140, 43015140, 47964392.45, 50633409.37, 58675956.95,
63973660.79, 84022385.5, 86476018.17, 100530101.81, 123786740.35,
218541356.23, 218541356.23, 222597742.97, 231634225.76, 16142060.85,
16142060.85, 25404698.48, 30182475.2, 37467151.21, 44220604.77,
59069003.47, 74919522.28, 81659857.97, 84330652.49, 88161080.7,
88827537.39, 89741960.87, 92955475.08, 93570451.1500001,
0, 0, 177073.45, 689328.44, 3480281.59, 9718277.91, 18408851.7,
37528650.63, 60876392.59, 82601349.71, 105744178.51, 124472383.39,
146234636.31, 161558300.02, 168511123.92, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, NA, 57397.33, 155949.08, 612826.62, 758796.79, 1074097.73,
1074097.73, 1271448.54, 2002583.13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
96463.61, 96463.61, 236815.32, 236815.32, 236815.32, 1025793.06,
1250898.56, 2078426.53), Postotak_iskorištenosti = c(0.101442804152861,
0.0920134173214, 0.0920134173214, 0.0596502660015698, 0.0604578051362542,
0.0700608474839968, 0.0763864643131506, 0.100325241235918,
0.10325495202736, 0.120035948224294, 0.146554054640891, 0.25531126922018,
0.25531126922018, 0.260050149150747, 0.270607033807275, 0.157464045903014,
0.157464045903014, 0.247820067386684, 0.294426759044177,
0.365487980302504, 0.431367184405227, 0.576211696900238,
0.730831781948699, 0.796583022657961, 0.822636332381099,
0.860001742479131, 0.866502954920449, 0.875423056397425,
0.906770537600448, 0.912769562199326, 0, 0, 0.000821595724647033,
0.00296043599181164, 0.0148941433046239, 0.0415591559080047,
0.0786380788318079, 0.158591654121197, 0.25594689367211,
0.341767677870294, 0.435052446794504, 0.507109811557543,
0.592242055242435, 0.653606589798265, 0.68173520663927, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00294082375875913, 0.00720368954026474,
0.0266462938278681, 0.0329932179218702, 0.0467028075794523,
0.0467028075794523, 0.0552838115678688, 0.0870742502940095,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00270686468491542, 0.00255878937519288,
0.00628175251474522, 0.00628175251474522, 0.00597289088686472,
0.0250228531814987, 0.0299492763182879, 0.0482885654585675
)), row.names = c(NA, -75L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any example data (post the output of `dput(HAMAG_pozivi_df)`) so I can't test, but the following should work:

```
HAMAG_pozivi_df %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~Ugovoreni_iznos_bespovratnih_potpora_HRK, 
    y = ~Broj_ugovora,                                                                                                
    size = ~Postotak_iskorištenosti,
    color = ~Poziv, 
    frame = ~Datum, 
    text = ~paste("<b>Poziv:</b>", Poziv, "<br><b>Postotak_iskorištenosti:</b>", Postotak_iskorištenosti),
    hovertemplate= paste("%{text}", "<extra></extra>")
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers', marker = list(sizeref = 0.15))
```

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately when I put your proposed code it says:                             Error: unexpected symbol in:
"        hovertemplate= paste("%{text}", "<extra></extra>")
        type"
>         mode = 'markers', marker = list(sizeref = 0.15))
Error: unexpected ',' in "        mode = 'markers',"                                                                  I am trying to understand plotly instructions but they are not really helpful.

Comment: I provided dput(HAMAG_small) above - its a smaller example of the data.

Comment: Hi, this code worked for me:
...code...and then:

    hoverinfo = 'text',
    text = paste('Poziv: ', HAMAG_pozivi_df$Poziv,
                 '<br>',
                 '% iskorištenosti sredstava: ', HAMAG_pozivi_df$Postotak_iskorištenosti),
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers',marker = list(sizeref = 0.15))